# How to set controller-wide variable in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

following scenario:

i want to set the body tag in each view like this:

```
<body id="<%= @controller %>">
```

how can i set a controller wide variable, so the @controller variable gets replaced with it? something like

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  @controller = "foo"
end
```

doesn't work...

any advice? thanks!

**EDIT:** thanks guys, i choose the `params[:controller]` way, works nice!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to go about it depending on your actual needs.

One way is to use a `before_filter` to initialize it before any methods are run.

If you're really just looking for the controller name, there are other options, like manipulating `controller_path` or `controller`, `params[:controller]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is it per controller only? Try looking into `before_filter` ?